# D3 library in R?

Tags: javascript, html, r, d3.js, visualization

I am working with the "r2d3" library in R (https://www.rstudio.com/blog/r2d3-r-interface-to-d3-visualizations/) - as I understand, this library is intended to perform javascript based data visualizations in R.

I would like to try and run the following visualization in R : https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/gallery/bubbles/

I loaded the data into R:

```
library(r2d3)
library(ggraph)

data(flare)
```

Then, I copied the entire "bubbles.js" script into a new R Markdown editor and clicked "knit to html". Then, I got the following output:

[image]

Clearly, I am doing something wrong.

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I tried running the following code in R Console:

```
r2d3(data = flare, d3_version = 4, script = "bubbles.js")
```

And this is the error I got:

[image]

Comment: Apparently whatever the lib outputted was JavaScript meant to work with d3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /../as I understand, this library is intended to perform javascript
> based data visualizations in R /../

It's more of an interface for existing D3 visualizations.

https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/index.html provides fairly good overview of the process, you should go through that first.
To get that gallery sample working, you first prepare a working directory where you have:

- [flare.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/r2d3/main/vignettes/gallery/bubbles/flare.csv)
- [bubbles.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/r2d3/main/vignettes/gallery/bubbles/bubbles.js)

Once you have made sure your working dir is the same where those files are (`getwed()` / `setwd()`), running

```r
library(r2d3)
r2d3(data = read.csv("flare.csv"), d3_version = 4, script = "bubbles.js")
```

in console / script / rmd should render those bubbles.
Or you could just clone the repo and have all sample files including Rmd-s -  https://github.com/rstudio/r2d3/tree/main/vignettes/gallery/bubbles

RStudio provides some support for D3 scripts, so you can also go through *File > New File > D3 Script* and paste the `bubbles.js` content there or open existing `bubbles.js` file. Assuming you have `flare.csv` file in working directory, you can click on a *Preview* to have it rendered in *Viewer* pane. That's what the

```js
// !preview r2d3 data = read.csv("flare.csv"), d3_version = 4
```

line in js script header is there for.